# Removing Last Record from BindingList Selects Last Row Causing DataGridView to Scroll

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView on a form and as I receive new data I'm inserting records to the beginning of a BindingList that is bound to the DataGridView.  When there are enough records for a vertical scrollbar to appear it stays at the top of the list.  So I'm always seeing the latest record at the top of the list.  This work fine up to this point.

However, when I add code to remove the last record of the list when it gets too long, the last record in the list is automatically selected causing the scrollbar to "scroll" to the last record in the list all the way at the bottom of the DataGridView.  I've even added a call to ClearSelection() before and after the call to RemoveAt but it still scrolls to the bottom.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You could always get an index or other such identifier of your selected DataGridViewRow before a record is removed.

In the bindingSource Changed event, you could then parse your data and set the correct row.

To set the first displayed DataGridViewRow, use:

```
DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
```

To select that same DataGridViewRow, use:

```
DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Remember to error check to ensure that index value is not -1 (none selected).